# Does Audrey Tomason's apocalypse equation thesis exist?

Tags: united-states, politics

Recently it has been claimed that Audrey Tomason, the US government's Director for Counter-Terrorism has written a master's thesis about an "apocalypse equation":

> [Audrey Tomason] wrote a master thesis [...] suggesting that it would be more humane for our world to undergo a “planned and controlled genocide” rather than to see it descend into the abyss of chaos it is now entering.
>
> [...]
>
> Ms Tomason argues in her thesis that our world’s population has been “artificially inflated” for the past nearly 100 years by a “non-sustainable” petrochemical and fossil fuel based global economy that if left “unchecked” could very well destroy all life on Earth, not just human beings.
>
> [[What Does It Mean news service](http://www.whatdoesitmean.com/index1477.htm)]

Other sources:

- Caution! May be virus infected. See comments: [Thread on WhenSHTF.com](http://www.whenshtf.com/showthread.php?40642-Tomason-s-Apocalypse-Equation-A-Heartless-Woman-s-Sinister-Proposal)
- [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=apocalypse%20equation)

Is there any evidence that a thesis written by Audrey Tomason exists? If so, is the content of this thesis really about an apocalypse equation as claimed in the links above? What is the form (mathematically) of that apocalypse equation? Is there any relation to the apocalypse equation by [Bradford_Lyttle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradford_Lyttle)?

Comment: Do you mean [Audrey Tomason, the 'Director for Counterterrorism'](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1383959/Who-Audrey-Tomason-The-mystery-woman-situation-room-photo.html) or some other person with the same name?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about Audrey Tomason, the Director for Counterterrorism.

Comment: Weird! When I visit the Harvard Kennedy School for Business, Audrey Tomason appears in the search results for an Alumni honor roll of donors: http://www.hks.harvard.edu/advanced-search?q=Audrey+Tomason - the excerpt includes her name, but when I click on the link, her name isn't on the page, suggesting it has been recently deleted. Woooooo!

Comment: Yesterday when I clicked on that **WhenSHTF.com** link I got hit with a bad virus.

Comment: @Mike, can you tell us more? What virus was it? I am not seeing anything untoward, and AVG Threat Labs haven't heard anything: http://www.avgthreatlabs.com/sitereports/domain/whenshtf.com

Comment: @Oddthinking: It's the link that goes "Tomason-s-Apocalypse-Equation-A-Heartless-Woman-s-Sinister-Proposal". As soon as I clicked I knew something was funny. My task manager disappeared & I couldn't restart it. I hard powered-down the machine, restarted and ran malwarebytes. It was about 5 things with names like TrojanFakeMS or something like that, both files and registry items. One of the things it did was remove lots of stuff from my start menu and desktop. I don't know yet if there's any more serious damage.

Comment: A bit more information about Audrey Tomason. She worked as Americorps*VISTA and Associate at ACCION International after Tufts. She is attending the Kennedy School's master's in public policy program and is scheduled to graduate in 2003. See http://www.tuftsgloballeadership.org/programs/epiic/epiic-alumni/1997

Comment: @Oddthinking: I just checked the log. It was PUM.Hijack.DisplayProperties, PUM.Hidden.Desktop, PUM.Hijack.TaskManager, and Trojan.FakeMS.

Comment: @Mike, sorry to hear about that; hope it all cleaned up well. That URL is still showing clean with tools like http://onlinelinkscan.com/. I wonder if it was another site, with a delayed reaction. I put a warning in the question.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Strange. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @asmaier: I think you mean a "master's thesis", not a "PHD thesis".

Comment: As I see, the only way this question could be answered is by finding full text, or at least abstract of that thesis in Harvard archives.

Comment: Apparently, her thesis was classified 'top secret', which is why you won't see it in any public university index...it is the state's last resort to fix the problems we are currently undergoing.

Answer (score 6):

Theses and dissertations, by their nature, are intended to be publicly available documents.  As such, all reputable universities of which I know *require* that theses be indexed in the school's library or archive.  ["Audrey Tomason" does not appear at all in the Tufts University library index.](http://library.tufts.edu/search~S1/?searchtype=a&searcharg=Tomason,%20Audrey&searchscope=1&SORT=D&extended=0&SUBMIT=Search&searchlimits=&searchorigarg=aAudrey%20Tomason)  According to Harvard's archives, [all abstracts of Masters theses written after 1988 are electronically available](http://hcl.harvard.edu/research/guides/dissertations/), however, the only link to "Audrey Tomason" on the Harvard library's index is for this paper:

- [*The United States' role in drug control policy for Afghanistan*](http://hollis.harvard.edu/?itemid=%7Clibrary/m/aleph%7C009117506). [Allison Cohen](http://www.linkedin.com/pub/allison-cohen-neale/4/b79/6b8) and Audrey Tomason.  John F. Kennedy School of Government Policy Analysis Exercises, 2003.

Therefore, I can only think of three possibilities:

- Audrey Tomason did not write a Master's thesis;
- she wrote a Master's thesis at a university other than Tufts or Harvard; or
- the record of her thesis was either accidentally or intentionally removed from the online index (or it was never included in the first place).

In response to [vartec](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/3790/vartec)'s comment about classification, if that is truly the case, then that falls under the third possibility I listed above and it is likely unverifiable unless a [FOIA](http://www.state.gov/m/a/ips/) request is made.  It should be noted, however, that there are restrictions on how and when the US government can classify civilian documents.  From [Executive Order 13562 Section 1.7 parts (b) and (c)](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Executive_Order_13526):

> (b) Basic scientific research information not clearly related to the national security shall not be classified.
> (c) Information may not be reclassified after declassification and release to the public under proper authority unless:
> ...
>     (2) the information may be reasonably recovered without bringing undue attention to the information;
> ...

A Master's thesis *should* (although not necessarily) constitute "basic scientific research".  Also, from the quotes in [asmaier](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3772/6629)'s question, it doesn't seem like the thesis is directly related to national security.  Finally, I interpret part (c)(2) to mean that once a thesis is made available publicly (especially on the Internet), it is likely difficult to increase its classification level.

Comment: it's allegedly "classified top secret by government"

Comment: I doubt there is a website which has a comprehensive list of master theses written at our institute. Yes, nominally it’s on public record but in reality this means that you have to actually *go there* and request the documents personally. If you’re lucky, an email or phone inquiry might also work.

Comment: I am not sure if it is comprehensive, but [your institute seems to do a pretty good job of posting them online](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ebisearch/search.ebi?db=ebiweb_main&t=ms+thesis&requestFrom=page1).  I've never seen a university that has a library and doesn't index master's theses on the library's website's public index.

Answer (score 3):

A partial answer:

In Bradford Lyttle's Apocalypse Equation is a stochastic model, initially proposed in 1982, linking the risk of (accidental) nuclear apocalypse with the number of nuclear weapons being stored. [[Ref](http://www.uspacifistparty.org/essays/EnolaGay-Apocalypse.html), [Ref](http://www.atarimagazines.com/creative/v9n5/196_The_apocalypse_equations.php)]

Audrey Tomason's alleged master's thesis is allegedly about economic collapse being triggered by an unsustainable oil industry. [[OP's ref](http://www.whatdoesitmean.com/index1477.htm)]

These are unrelated issues, and therefore there is no relation to terms "Apocalypse Equation" between the two uses.